# R: No quotes when passing a string as an argument

Tags: r, function

I would like to know how to make R treat an argument as a string even if it does not have quotes.  Perhaps with unknown function `bar`:

```
foo <- function(x) bar(a))
foo(a abadsf 23)
[1] "a abadsf 23"
```

Comment: you want to print "a" while there is a variable a defined as "foo" or did I not understand at all  ?

Comment: No, I just wrote `a="foo"` so that it was clear that I did not want to print "foo".  Perhaps I should have just given `(function(x) print(bar(a)))(a)

[1] "a"`

Comment: that's what I said. You want to print "a" HOWEVER there is a variable **a** that is defined as "foo". Is it correct ?

Comment: I'm afraid the part inside foo() will produce a syntax error everytime

Comment: Yes to @T_O. I'm sure there's a duplicate question here that has a full answer why, but I can't seem to find it; anyone else remember it and is having better luck searching?

Comment: Here are two similar questions, though neither specifically address the spaces issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13040120  http://stackoverflow.com/q/5011348

Comment: why exactly do you want to do this?

Comment: I would like to program a batch of functions that are much less syntactically demanding. For instance `paste()` could be greatly simplified with a syntax `paste(I am a string because it is obvious and the following is my age:, age)`. Is this so crazy? I have a lot of other examples

Comment: But is having quotes really "syntactically demanding"? And is a string without them really "greatly simplified"? :s If I understand the example you've given, you seem to want the comma to separate your "string" from a variable called age. How do you want the function to know that "age" at the end shouldn't also be printed as "age"? And the function you're proposing presumably also won't accept strings containing commas unless you're escaping them in some way. You'd be introducing a lot of trouble and ambiguity just to evade the use of quotes...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this doing what you want?

```
printname <- function(x) deparse(substitute(x))
printname(foo)
[1] "foo"
printname(bar)
[1] "bar"
```

edit:
This probably won't be considered acceptable, depending on where these values are coming from, but to include spaces you could try something like:

```
print.input = function(y=readline()) return(y)
```

usage in script:

```
print.input()
input with spaces
[1] "input with spaces"
```

Comment: My mistake, it is working for that example but not working generally. `printname(foo foo)
Error: unexpected symbol in "printname(foo foo"`

Comment: @fsmart Sorry, I didn't realise spaces were required at the time. I've added something, but I expect that you have some reason for looking for this capability and that the solution above won't be sufficient for it.

Comment: interesting. thank you for the idea but it is not really what I was going after

Answer (score 1):

You can use quote, but this doesn't work with spaces.

```
deparse(quote(abc))
## [1] "abc"
deparse(quote(abc 1))
## Error: unexpected numeric constant in "deparse(quote(abc 1"
```